# I have exported properly but still getting error for 1 component ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

App.js Component

```
import React from 'react';
import StartPage from "./StartPage";
import LoginPage from "./LoginPage";
import SignUp from "./SignUp";
import Route from "./Route";

const App = () => {

    const onClickStart = () => {
        window.location.pathname = "/signup";
    }
    console.log(window.location.pathname);

    return (
        <div>

            <Route path="/">
                <StartPage onClickStart={onClickStart}/>
            </Route>

            <Route path="/signup">
                <SignUp />
            </Route>

            <Route path="/login">
                <LoginPage />
            </Route>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

LoginPage & StartPage are working perfectly but there's an error in SignUp page.

Error

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `SignUp`.

SignUp component

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import BackgroundImage from "../img/background.png";

const SignUp = () => {
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();

    return (
        <div class="bg_image"
        style={{
          backgroundImage: 'url('+BackgroundImage+')',
          backgroundPosition: 'center',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          width: '100vw',
          margin: '0px',
          padding: '0px',
          height: '100vh'}}>
              <Card>
                  <Card.body>
                      <h2 className = "text-center mb-4">Signup</h2>
                      <Form>
                          <Form.group id="email">
                            <Form.label>Email</Form.label>
                            <Form.Control type="email" ref={emailRef} required />
                          </Form.group>

                          <Form.group id="password">
                            <Form.label>Password</Form.label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordRef} required />
                          </Form.group>

                          <Form.group id="password-confirm">
                            <Form.label>Password Confirmation</Form.label>
                            <Form.Control type="password" ref={passwordConfirmRef} required />
                          </Form.group>
                      </Form>

                      <Button className="w-100" type="submit">Signup</Button>
                  </Card.body>
              </Card>
              <div className = "w-100 text-center mt-2">
                  Already have an account? Login
              </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't quite specified the compound components correctly. The compound components/elements you are trying to use aren't exported.

- `Card.body` should be [Card.Body](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/cards/#card-body-props)
- `Form.group` should be [Form.Group](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-group-props)
- `Form.label` should be [Form.Label](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#form-label-props)